# Delete messages in Mailgun

Tags: email, mailgun

I made a terrible mistake and delete a code "break" so mailgun sends numerous mails and continue to send. Is it possible to purge the queue or prevent them to send?

Best.

Answer (score 0):

The mailgun API allows for [deleting messages](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#deleting-stored-messages)